# Greasemonkey iframe content access jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I had the wrong impression that using Greasemonkey would allow me unrestricted access to iframe's elements as jQuery selectors..

The HTML page example:

```
     <html>
         <body>
              <div id='content'>

                     //Here is the first iframe

                 <iframe src='bla.php'>

                       <html>
                       <body>
                       <div id='content2'>

                          //Here another iframe is inserted
                          <iframe src='bla2.php'>
                                //Here some simple elements

                                   <div id="goal">
                                          My password is Secret
                                  </div>

                          </iframe>


                       </div>
                     </body>
                    <html>
                 </iframe>

              </div>
         </body>
     <html>
```

So I'm trying to find if the #goal selector contains Secret, and tried using

```
     $('#goal').text().search('Secret');
```

Obviously it doesn't work, tried getting the whole DOM as a variable and used the variable.indexOf('Secret') .. but after debugging, the DOM content does not contain the iframes contents.

Any solution I may use ? Some Greasemonkey settings I may apply ?.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframes are treated different, jQuery has a second optional argument, related to the used document DOM, default is document, and setting it to the iframe document will work.

```
   $('#goal', frames[0][0].document ).text().search('Secret');
```